# CLOB para string e vice-versa

Tags: c#, oracle, imagem, base64, blob

Estou desenvolvendo um web server onde tenho que armazenar imagens em `String` de `Base64` trocadas pelos `desktop`, `mobile` e `website` para o banco de dados da `Oracle`, porém pesquisei bastante e vi algumas alternativas que são:

armazenar em string mesmo como se fosse um texto, mas tenho que converter pra `CLOB` pois é extremamente grande, ultrapassando os 4000 bytes o que não é recomendado.

Ou transformar em imagem novamente depois em `BLOB`, armazenar e vice versa.

Qual alternativa é melhor? Alguém ai tem métodos de exemplo?

Se alguém tem alguma alternativa nova me ajuda também.

Obrigado :)

Answer (score 3):

Fazer leitura de `CLOB` não é da mesma maneira que de outras colunas, pois essa não possui um tipo "primitivo" - char, int, datetime, etc.

> Primeiramente entenda o seguinte: **CLOB não é uma coluna da tabela.**

No design da tabela, uma coluna CLOB, até é criada da mesma forma que as demais, mas fisicamente ela é uma outra tabela, oculta, onde seus registros" possuem relação *One-To-One* com a tabela principal. Isso por conta da complexidade do metadados de um CLOB.

E isso tudo vale para colunas BLOB também.

> Importante: **Tente nunca fazer `SELECT *` em uma table com coluna `CLOB`**

Como boa prática, só traga a coluna CLOB quando for conveniente, fazendo o simples `SELECT COLUNA_CLOB FROM TABELA WHERE ID = @ID`. Isso, basicamente, para evitar *processing-intensive* do Oracle ao tentar ligar a tabela principal à tabela interna CLOB e criar um *fetch* legível pela sua cláusula SQL.

> Agora: **Como ler um CLOB para string?**

Quando trabalhei com C# e Oracle - por volta dos anos 2003-2005 - tinhamos que fazer um script para fazer o *download* dos dados. Hoje ocorre o mesmo, mas agora a Oracle encapsulate essa rotina no seu Provider .NET.

Depois de uma rápida pesquisa, encontrei a nova sintaxe [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736242/converting-a-large-clob-object-to-net-string-to-put-into-a-datagridview-cell/10815819#10815819).

```
// sendo "i" o índice da sua coluna CLOB 
var texto = reader.IsDBNull(i) 
    : string.Empty
    ? (string) reader.GetOracleClob(i).Value
```

Veja aqui a [documentação de `GetOracleLob(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#i1005577)

> Por fim: **Como gravar/atualizar uma coluna CLOB?**

Na própria documentação da Oracle encontrar o método para fazer o que precisa. Veja aqui sobre [GetOracleClobForUpdate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#i1005619).

Segue o exemplo deles:

```
/* Database Setup, if you have not done so yet.
connect scott/tiger@oracle 
CREATE TABLE empInfo (
empno NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
empName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
hiredate DATE,
salary NUMBER(7,2),
jobDescription Clob,
byteCodes BLOB
);

Insert into empInfo(EMPNO,EMPNAME,JOBDESCRIPTION,byteCodes) values 
(1,'KING','SOFTWARE ENGR', '5657');
Insert into empInfo(EMPNO,EMPNAME,JOBDESCRIPTION,byteCodes) values 
(2,'SCOTT','MANAGER', '5960');
commit;

*/
// C#

using System;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; 
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

class GetOracleClobForUpdateSample
{
  static void Main()
  {
    string constr = "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=oracle";
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
    con.Open();

    // Get the job description for empno = 1
    string cmdStr = "SELECT JOBDESCRIPTION, EMPNO FROM EMPINFO where EMPNO = 1";
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdStr, con);

    // Since we are going to update the OracleClob object, we will
    //  have to create a transaction
    OracleTransaction txn = con.BeginTransaction();

    // Get the reader
    OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    // Declare the variables to retrieve the data in EmpInfo
    OracleClob jobDescClob;

    // Read the first row
    reader.Read();

    if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
    {
      jobDescClob = reader.GetOracleClobForUpdate(0);

      // Close the reader
      reader.Close();

      // Update the job description Clob object
      char[] jobDesc = "-SALES".ToCharArray();
      jobDescClob.Append(jobDesc, 0, jobDesc.Length);

      // Now commit the transaction
      txn.Commit();
      Console.WriteLine("Clob Column successfully updated");
    }
    else
      reader.Close();

    // Close the connection
    con.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Isso é uma bela e boa resposta, Obrigado :)

Comment: @FelipeRibeiro ainda sim fecharam a pergunta... :(